# What is the practical usage of an array of an unbounded wildcard parameterized type?

Tags: java, generics, collections

I am reading through [AngelikaLangerParametrizedTypeWorkAround](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#How%20can%20I%20work%20around%20the%20restriction%20that%20there%20are%20no%20arrays%20whose%20component%20type%20is%20a%20concrete%20instantiation%20of%20a). I do understand many
of the concepts here, i do understand what is unbounded wild card parametrized type. Though
quoting from the reference it states that :-

```
static void test() { 
  Pair<?,?>[] intPairArr = new Pair<?,?>[10] ;  
  addElements(intPairArr);  
  Pair<Integer,Integer> pair = intPairArr[1];  // error -1 
  Integer i = pair.getFirst();  
  pair.setSecond(i); 
} 
static void addElements(Object[] objArr) { 
  objArr[0] = new Pair<Integer,Integer>(0,0); 
  objArr[1] = new Pair<String,String>("","");    // should fail, but succeeds 
}
```

> In the case of the unbounded wildcard parameterized type we are
> additionally restricted in how we can use the array elements, because
> the compiler prevents certain operations on the unbounded wildcard
> parameterized type.  In essence, arrays of raw types and unbounded
> wildcard parameterized types are semantically very different from what
> we would express with an array of a concrete wildcard parameterized
> type.  For this reason they are not a good workaround and only
> acceptable when the superior efficiency of arrays (as compared to
> collections) is of paramount importance.

I have two specific questions here.

1. What is practical usage of unbounded wild-card parameterized type? It's clearly evident from the example, that you can add elements to the array but while retrieving, it issues a compiler error?
2. What does the article mean, when it states that, these wild-card parameterized are only acceptable when superior efficiency of arrays is of paramount importance?

Can someone elaborbate on this issue?

Comment: It looks like you have two questions here; can you be more specific in what you're asking? Do you want to know (1) what the point of wildcards at all is and (2) why the spec makes the comment about arrays over collections?

Comment: hi chrylis i have edited my question.

Comment: You should assign `intPairArr[0]` to the `pair` variable, because it's `Pair<Integer, Integer>`, while intPairArr[1] is `Pair<String, String>`.

Comment: @kocko. That's anyway not the point of his question.

Comment: My point is why usage of wild-card parameterized wild card are even allowed if their practical usages are so limited and i am not concerned for raw types.

Comment: Wildcard types are the *only* generic thing allowed with arrays. Your proposal, then, is to ban all generic types from arrays.

Comment: No @MarkoTopolnik. My point is just after reading article that it has a very little practical usage as its a heterogeneous array. My point is why it is allowed if it has a little usage? I am confused about second point in my question as well.

Comment: @benz But the alternative to "allowed" is "banned", isn't it? So what options are left other than to allow an impractical thing, and allow nothing at all? The semantics of arrays is as it has always been, and Generics is a largely unsuccessful tack-on. Therein lies the problem.

Comment: On your second point, it means "use collections and not arrays, except if you have a well-known reason to use arrays, which is superior performance".

Comment: thankyou very much marko for your explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First about this code:

```
static void addElements(Object[] objArr) { 
  objArr[0] = new Pair<Integer,Integer>(0,0); 
  objArr[1] = new Pair<String,String>("","");    // should fail, but succeeds 
}
```

Here you're passing an argument of type `Object[]` to `addElements` method. Hence compiler will allow you to add anything that is an `Object`. Even this code will also compile:

```
static void addElements(Object[] objArr) { 
  objArr[0] = new Pair<Integer,Integer>(0,0); 
  objArr[1] = new Pair<String,String>("","");
  objArr[2] = new Date(); // won't be a compilation error here
}
```

However you will get run time exceptions as generic types are compile time checks and run time casts.

Now your question about why even allow raw types in generics?

One of the reasons why it is allowed to have backward compatibility with older JVMs and also for the cases when developer of the Interface may not know all the types that can be supplied at run time. Your `error-1` does need casting from raw types to specific types:

```
// this should compile
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Pair<Integer, Integer> pair = (Pair<Integer, Integer>) intPairArr[0];  // NO error -1
```

#### EDIT:

**About wildcards dilemma:**

Let's take a very simple example of using unbounded wildcards:

```
Pair<?, ?> intPair = new Pair<Integer, Integer>(4, 9);
Object val2 = intPair.getSecond();
System.out.printf("val2: %d, isInt: %s%n", val2, (val2 instanceof Integer));
intPair.setFirst( null ); // assigning null will be allowed
```

It will compile & run and produce this expected output:

```
val2: 9, isInt: true
```

However this will not compile:

```
intPair.setSecond((Object) new Integer(10)); // compile error
intPair.setSecond(new Integer(10)); // compile error
```

In an `unbounded wildcard` parameterized type such as `Pair<?,?>` the type of the fields and the return types of the methods would be `unknown` i.e.  both fields would be of type `?`. The setter methods would take an argument of type `?` and the getter methods would return a `?`.

*In this situation the compiler will not let you assign anything to the field or pass anything to the setter methods*. The reason is that the compiler cannot make sure that the object that we are trying to pass as an argument of a set method is of the expected type, since the expected type is unknown.

In contrast, the getter methods can be invoked and it returns an object of an unknown type, which we can assign to a reference variable of type Object.

So you are right that in a way that it does restrict its usage, as evident above in the small example where values can be assigned during construction but not when you try calling setter methods.

However you can increase the usefulness of your code by using **wildcards with lower bound type** like this:

```
Pair<? super Object, ? super Object> intPair = new Pair<Object, Object>(4, 9);
Object val2 = intPair.getSecond();
System.out.printf("val2: %s, isInt: %s%n", val2, (val2 instanceof Integer));
intPair.setSecond(10);
val2 = intPair.getSecond();
System.out.printf("val2: %s, isInt: %s%n", val2, (val2 instanceof Integer));
```

Now this not only compiles but runs also with expected results:

```
val2: 9, isInt: true
val2: 10, isInt: true
```

About your 2nd question: I am quoting the para directly from your linked article:

> By using arrays of raw types or unbounded wildcard parameterized types
>   we give away the static type checks that a homogenous sequence would
>   come with.  As a result we must use explicit casts or we risk
>   unexpected ClassCastException s.  In the case of the unbounded
>   wildcard parameterized type we are additionally restricted in how we
>   can use the array elements, because the compiler prevents certain
>   operations on the unbounded wildcard parameterized type.  In essence,
>   arrays of raw types and unbounded wildcard parameterized types are
>   semantically very different from what we would express with an array
>   of a concrete wildcard parameterized type.  For this reason they are
>   not a good workaround and only acceptable when the superior efficiency
>   of arrays (as compared to collections) is of paramount importance.

Author is stressing that unbounded wildcards in arrays is *not a good workaround* because of its restrictions and superior efficiency is only in the context of `arrays vs collections`.

Comment: i totally agree to the usage of raw types. But raw types are entirely different from wildcard parameterized types. My question revolves around, why wildcard parametrized types are even allowed if the usage is so limited. Can you have a look at my edited question please.

Comment: He is asking for why `Pair<?,?>[]` allowed, which is not a raw type. Secondly, your last example might compile fine, but will throw `ClassCastException` at runtime.

Comment: @Benz: Sorry just noticed your edited question. Let me go through that and then respond back.

Comment: @RohitJain: Yes that's correct, `Pair<Integer, Integer> pair = (Pair<Integer, Integer>) intPairArr[0];` will not throw any runtime `ClassCastException` but it will still require casting and `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`

Comment: @anubhava. Yeah sure, but that still doesn't answer the concrete question. Your answer is no-where related to the actual question.

Comment: @RohitJain: Since actual question came after edit, I will add my answer for it after due diligence.

Comment: @anubhava thanks for wonderful explanation added. I have one query when you say, intPair.setFirst( null ); // assigning null will be allowed. What is the practical usage of setting the first to null?

Comment: That might be practical usage of assigning null to some fields in programming practice. Remember code did assign some non-null values during construction and if for some reason coder wants to set it to null for certain checks down the road it will be allowed. (Though I am in sync with your general assessment that its usage will be somewhat restricted since you cannot call setter with any value other than `null`).

Comment: @benz: You're most welcome. Actually I am thankful to you for posting such a great question. I learnt quite a few things while reading your linked article and understanding semantics of your posted example code. If I could I would have upvoted your question 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

The unbounded wildcard is basically syntactic sugar for the case when you need a flexible generic type (such as when accepting a `Collection`) but don't actually care about what the type is (you're just printing its `toString`). You could do the same thing with a generic method, but it gets clumsy and doesn't buy you anything. An unbounded wildcard lets you dispense with that.

The explanation about arrays is simply reminding you that in most cases, it's better to use a collection type than an array unless you really can't afford the extra cost of a collection. In your example, you found out why: When you pass in the array as an `Object[]`, you're telling the compiler that it's perfectly okay to add *any* object to that array, and since `Pair<Integer,Integer>` is an `Object`, the compiler lets you do that. Depending on your other code (you haven't quite triggered an exception yet), you probably now have heap pollution in `intPairArr`.